# How to get top 5 products with highest views?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am new to LINQ and trying to build a website with MVC and LINQ. I want to display top 5 products with the most views. I have 2 tables like below, I am explaining as simple as possible.

```
PRODUCT
-------
ID
NAME

PRODUCT_VIEWS_TABLE
-------
ID
PRODUCT_ID
```

Everytime a product is viewed, I insert a new row to the PRODUCT_VIEWS_TABLE. How can I write the LINQ query for this?

```
(from c in db.PRODUCT select c).Take(5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var topProductsIds = db.PRODUCT_VIEWS_TABLE // table with a row for each view of a product
    .GroupBy(x => x.PRODUCT_ID) //group all rows with same product id together
    .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count()) // move products with highest views to the top
    .Take(5) // take top 5
    .Select(x => x.Key) // get id of products
    .ToList(); // execute query and convert it to a list

var topProducts = db.PRODUCTS // table with products information
    .Where(x=> topProductsIds.Contains(x.ID)); // get info of products that their Ids are retrieved in previous query
```

Comment: .Select() and .OrderByDescending() lines dont compile.

Comment: first .Select from the top, and ..OrderByDescending below it. It says "Invalid Anonymous...."

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
var top5 = productViews
             .GroupBy(view => view.ProductId)   // group views by product
             .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count()) // order from most- to least-viewed
             .Take(5)                           // take the top 5
             .Select(g => g.First().Product);   // fetch the corresponding product
```

Comment: that was not stipulated in the problem.

Comment: I just mentioned that for more information, +1 for simpler LINQ

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var topProducts = m_context.PRODUCTS
    .Join(m_context.PRODUCT_VIEW, product=> product.Id, view => view.ProductId,
        (product, view ) => new { ProductId = product.Id, ViewId = view.Id})
    .GroupBy(g => g.ProductId)
    .Select(s => new {
        Id = s.Key,
        ViewCount= s.Count()
    })
    .OrderByDescending(o => o.ViewCount)
    .Take(5).ToList();
```